# how javascript send blank line to php?

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I write a demo like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = init;

    function init() {
        var btn = document.getElementById('submit');
        btn.onclick = function() {
            var str = document.getElementById('testText').value;
            alert(str);
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = 'test.php?str=' + str;
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                var str = xmlHttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById('testText').value = str.toLocaleUpperCase();

            };
            xmlHttp.open('GET', url, true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        };

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="test.php" method="POST">
        <textarea name="testText" id="testText" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It send a GET to server, and the php just return what it get, then js show it by uppercase(write this because of system ask me to write more detail of code)
I write some text in `textarea` tag like

```
write some thing

write other thing
```

and output is

```
WRITE SOME THING WRITE OTHER THING
```

but I want to remain the blank lines, and expect output like this

```
WRITE SOME THING

WRITE OTHER THING
```

how should I do?

Comment: Try [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) in your `test.php`

Comment: @Fred-ii- this wouldn't result in `WRITE SOME THING <br> WRITE OTHER THING` since its a `textarea` element?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I thought the OP could have used that in their `test.php` file instead.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Now Quentin used it in his answer below lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send your data to PHP, you need to convert your text into URL format.

```
var url = 'test.php?str=' + encodeURIComponent(str);
```

When you output the PHP into an HTML document, you need to convert your text into HTML.

Most elements do not treat whitespace as significant, so you need to convert the new lines into line break elements or do some other kind of formatting. (In general, you want to use something smarter, like Markdown syntax, but I'll use nl2br for this simplistic example):

```
<div>
<?php
    $data = $_GET['str'];
    $safe_data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $formatted_data = nl2br($safe_data);
    echo $formatted_data;
?>
</div>
```

or, if you are outputting into an element with significant whitespace

```
<textarea>
<?php
    $data = $_GET['str'];
    $safe_data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    echo $safe_data;
?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NewLine character entity](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref), which can be expressed using any of the following:

> ```
> &NewLine;
> &#x0000A;
> &#10;
> ```

Like so:

```
write some thing&NewLine;write other thing
```

...or:

```
write some thing&#x0000A;write other thing
```

...or:

```
write some thing&#10;write other thing
```

#### Demo

```html
<textarea>write some thing&NewLine;write other thing</textarea>

<textarea>write some thing&#x0000A;write other thing</textarea>

<textarea>write some thing&#10;write other thing</textarea>
```

Comment: You can use a normal new line character in a textarea. There is no need to use an entity at all.

Comment: @Quentin `\n`? Not in Chrome you can't... How do you suggest populating a `textarea` with a new line through PHP without using the NewLine entity?

Comment: `echo "<textarea>foo\nbar</textarea>";`

Comment: @Quentin in your JSFiddle demo: `document.querySelector('textarea').innerHTML.charCodeAt(7)` returns `10`, which is exactly what the `&NewLine` character is converted into.

Comment: Yes. You *can* represent the new line with a character reference instead of a new line, but there isn't any point. Using an actual new line is quicker and easier.